# Sharing an item on Facebook, I am getting an error in Manifest.xml file

Tags: android, facebook, metadata, share, manifest

I have a button in my application, and when I click on that button, the sharing dialogue will open and I want to share it on facebook. However, before the application opens, it gives the following error. I use Firebase Authantication, is this about it?
But you have no option to sign in with facebook, you can only login with your email address.
when I add "tools:replace="android:value", this time the application opens but the button is not functioning. what can I do?

this is my manifest.xml File;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.orderfood.teknomerkez.orderfood">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_ID"
            'tools:replace="android:value" // AFTER ADDING THIS, BUTTON IS NOT WORKING />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="OrderFood"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".FoodList" />
        <activity android:name=".FoodDetail" />
        <activity android:name=".Cart" />
        <activity android:name=".OrderStatus" />

        <service android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseMessaging">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGİNG_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have controlled all my codes that need to initialize values and etc.. There is no problem in my codes.

this is my error;

```
 Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId@value value=(@string/facebook_ID) from AndroidManifest.xml:16:13-48
    is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-60 value=(@string/facebook_application_id).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-16:51 to override.
```

Comment: Don't add this line: `tools:replace="android:value"`... Try to update Android Studio, it worked for me when I experienced a similar issue...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but I already have the latest version of Android Studio and plugins installed.
it doesnt work :(

Comment: tried both of them. as I told, when ı add this tools:replace = "android:value" button is not working. and it happened same again.

Comment: It seems like this meta-data tag is already defined in some firebase package. Try to rename the `facebook_ID` resource name to `facebook_application_id` in the `strings` folder in your app.

Comment: Now, app opened but button still not working. I have controlled all button functions and no mistake.

Comment: Did you try to removing the meta-data tag completely?

Comment: yeah, I removed all meta-data tag but button is still not working

Comment: Thanks for help bro it worked now. I didnt remove meta-data. I have restarted my facebook account then it works. of course renaming facebook_ID resource name to facebook_application_id in the strings folder in my app.

Comment: Glad it worked out :)